Prove that there does not exists a Symplectic form in $S^3\times T^3$
Let $S^3\subset \mathbb C^2$ be the 3-sphere and $T^3=S^1\times S^1\times S^1$.

I am trying to show that there does not exist a symplectic form $\omega$ in $S^3\times T^3$.

As far as I know, the unique 'simple' necessary condition for the existence of a symplectic form is that the manifold must be of even dimension (as $S^3\times T^3$) and that $\omega\wedge \omega\wedge\omega$ must be a volume form in $S^3\times T^3$. Is there another available condition to check that $S^3\times T^3$ does not admit a symplectic form?

Do you know how to prove $S^4$ does not admit a symplectic form?

A slightly different hint than Michael Alabanese's: is it possible for a cohomology class like $[\omega \wedge \omega \wedge \omega]$ (with $\omega$ a differential $2$-form) to be nonzero here?
